# How to catch a 404 (Not Found) or parsererror when using jQuery to call a Rest service?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/Proxy/service.php",
}).done(function() {
    console.log("rdy");
});
```

Now I want to know how to prevent jQuery to get a 404 (Not Found) or parsererror?
When I e.g. can not reach localhost I will get a 404. But what can I do to catch this error and not show it in the console?

EDIT: localhost/Proxy/service.php is my REST service

Comment: there is nothing you can do which will prevent it from showing up in the console...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.fail`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/Proxy/service.php",
}).done(function() {
    console.log("rdy");
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Error!\r\n" + textStatus);
});
```

Most browsers allow you to disable a particular type of errors, like HTTP errors. See the screenshot below of the Firefox Developer Tools:

[image: Firefox Developer Tools]

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/Proxy/service.php",
    statusCode: {
    404: function() {
        //Catch 404
    }
  }
}).done(function() {
    console.log("rdy");
});
```

Nothing you can do about the console log unfortunately.